# "insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment " message in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am getting this error recently and not sure which causes this issue. When I run my code on Tomcat server 7.0.35, I get the following message:

```
mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file
mmap failed for CEN and END part of zip file

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32756 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
An error report file with more information is saved as:
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/hs_err_pid14852.log
```

UPDATE :
My application is designed to read mails and attachments and download them after parsing it in required format the count of unread messages is 113498 (inbox) the app terminates in between

Comment: Is that a 32bit JVM?

Comment: Are you running with defaults? If not what are your -Xmx and -Xms settings if any?

Comment: yes it is 32bit JVM
running with defaults

Comment: Its a 32bit JVM . running with defaults .what are required changes @DaveG

Comment: how it got fixed any idea